# F# Type Providers and REST apis

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-3.0

Is there any reason why the default plug and play F# type providers to web services is soap based wsdl? Is it because of a lack of formal contracts in REST? Such that each REST api may differ significantly and hence making a general REST provider difficult to provide?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type providers need machine-readable type schema to do their jobs well.

Answer (score 7):

Type providers need schema. So you could use [Open Data Protocol](http://www.odata.org/) that is REST + schema. For that task you could use [ODataTypeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362325%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is already implemented.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is because there is no way to know how the API looks. Humans can read the documentation, but the Type Provider cannot. Other APIs have XML specifications, so they are easier.